# Get post based on Tags and Categories together

Tags: wordpress

Please help me to sort out this problem in wordpress.

How I can get posts using WP_query based on both tags(multiple ID's) and categories(multiple ID's) at same time.

Here is the code.

For example we have these tags and caegory ID's.
Tags ID =1,2 ( These tags have 2 posts)

Categories ID =1,2 ( These categories have also 2 posts)

$tags=explode(',',$_GET['tag_id']); // Convert to array

$cats=explode(',',$_GET['cat_id']); // Convert to array

$cat_posts = new WP_query(array( 'tag__in' => $tags, 'cat' => $cats  ));

This code should return 4 posts but 0 posts.

I also tried category__in and other related to tags properties.

Thanks in advance.